# Why a ACR38U-CCID always return 0x6e 0x00?

Tags: linux, smartcard, apdu, pcsc, pyscard

Am working on a project to read from and write data to smart cards. The Card Reader am using is `ACR38U-H1` from `ACS`.   Following their `APDU` commands, I have being able to get access to the card and read some data. But am suspecting that I still have not being able to read the exact data inside, because always I get a response to the command `APDU` `0x6e 0x00, 0x00` instead of`0x90 0x00`.

What am I doing wrong?
Maybe the problem is in the smart card?

Python code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from smartcard.scard import *
import smartcard.util


SELECT = [
    #0xA0, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x3F, 0x00
    0XFF, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x05
]

COMMAND = [
    0x00, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0B
]

try:
    hresult, hcontext = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER)
    if hresult != SCARD_S_SUCCESS:
        raise Exception('Failed to establish context : ' +
            SCardGetErrorMessage(hresult))
    print 'Context established!'

    try:
        hresult, readers = SCardListReaders(hcontext, [])
        if hresult != SCARD_S_SUCCESS:
            raise Exception('Failed to list readers: ' +
                SCardGetErrorMessage(hresult))
        print 'PCSC Readers:', readers

        if len(readers) < 1:
            raise Exception('No smart card readers')

        reader = readers[0]
        print "Using reader:", reader

        try:
            hresult, hcard, dwActiveProtocol = SCardConnect(hcontext, reader,
                SCARD_SHARE_SHARED, SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1 | SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1)
            if hresult != SCARD_S_SUCCESS:
                raise Exception('Unable to connect: ' +
                    SCardGetErrorMessage(hresult))
            print 'Connected with active protocol', dwActiveProtocol

            try:
                hresult, response = SCardTransmit(hcard, dwActiveProtocol,
                    SELECT)
                if hresult != SCARD_S_SUCCESS:
                    raise Exception('Failed to transmit: ' +
                        SCardGetErrorMessage(hresult))
                print 'Select: ' + smartcard.util.toHexString(response,
                    smartcard.util.HEX)
#==========================================================================
                hresult, response = SCardTransmit(hcard, dwActiveProtocol,
                    COMMAND)
                if hresult != SCARD_S_SUCCESS:
                    raise Exception('Failed to transmit: ' +
                        SCardGetErrorMessage(hresult))
                print 'Command: ' + smartcard.util.toHexString(response,
                    smartcard.util.HEX)
# =========================================================================
            finally:
                hresult = SCardDisconnect(hcard, SCARD_UNPOWER_CARD)
                if hresult != SCARD_S_SUCCESS:
                    raise Exception('Failed to disconnect: ' +
                        SCardGetErrorMessage(hresult))
                print 'Disconnected'

        except Exception, message:
            print "Exception:", message

    finally:
        hresult = SCardReleaseContext(hcontext)
        if hresult != SCARD_S_SUCCESS:
            raise Exception('Failed to release context: ' +
                    SCardGetErrorMessage(hresult))
        print 'Released context.'

except Exception, message:
    print "Exception:", message
```

Result of this code:

```
Context established!
PCSC Readers: ['ACS ACR38U-CCID 00 00']
Using reader: ACS ACR38U-CCID 00 00
Connected with active protocol 2
Select: 0x6E 0x00
Command: 0x67 0x00
Disconnected
Released context.
```

Result of open-tool:

```
[17:06:00]:~$ opensc-tool -s ff:a4:00:00:01:05
Using reader with a card: ACS ACR38U-CCID 00 00
Sending: FF A4 00 00 01 05 
Received (SW1=0x6E, SW2=0x00)
```

Comment: What smartcard are you trying to read from?

Comment: @MichaelRoland, this is card of Health card of Russian Federation
(Params: `ISO 7816 T=0, T=1,EMV, CAC, 2/3 BUS I2C/Extended I2C memory cards`)

Comment: Are you sure this one is a memory card? Can you post output of `opensc-tool -a`. I guess it is a normal `T=0` or `T=1` card which does not require those `0xFF` APDUs (which are actually meant for the reader and not for the card). Where did you get these params -- they seem to me as reader capabilities and not card ones.

Comment: @vlp, `~$ opensc-tool -a
Using reader with a card: ACS ACR38U-CCID 00 00
3b:f7:13:00:00:81:31:fe:45:46:4f:4d:53:4f:4d:53:a9`.

Comment: Does `opensc-tool -s 00:a4:04:0c:09:66:6f:6d:73:5f:72:6f:6f:74` and `opensc-tool -s 00:a4:04:0c:07:46:4f:4d:53:5f:49:44` return `9000`?

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/RomanKharin/62419218414a8b83ac1a) might be interesting for you...good luck!

Comment: @vlp, Thank you. It's worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `SELECT_CARD_TYPE` APDU command (0xFF00000101) which is meant to be used with **I2C memory cards** (up to 16 kilobits specifically) -- see section 9.3.1.1 in the [reader reference manual](http://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/3454/REF-ACR38x-CCID-6.05.pdf).

This `SELECT_CARD_TYPE` command (having `CLA` set to `0xFF`) is not addressed to the card but to the reader (which refuses it as the card does not use I2C).

Your card is a microprocessor card speaking [T=1 protocol](https://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3bf71300008131fe45464f4d534f4d53a9) so you need to use "normal" ISO 7816 APDUs -- which ones should be specified in your card documentation.

Nevertheless there is a [script](https://gist.github.com/RomanKharin/62419218414a8b83ac1a) for [Smart Card Shell 3](http://www.openscdp.org/scsh3/index.html) tool which seems to read (and in a limited way emulate) FOMS card (I have not tried).

Given the script source it seems that card supports standard ISO 7816-4 `SELECT` and `READ_BINARY` APDU commands which are used behind [`new CardFile()`](http://www.openscdp.org/scsh3/cardfile.html#Constructor) and [`CardFile.readBinary()`](http://www.openscdp.org/scsh3/cardfile.html#readBinary).

Good luck!

Disclaimer: I have worked neither with any FOMS card nor with the scsh3 tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT = [
    #0xA0, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x3F, 0x00
    0XFF, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x05
]
```

Here it seems you are trying to select MF ( AID = 3F00 on commented # command)   **OR** Command seems wrong because no AID is of 1 byte length , Please check your command

```
 0XFF, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x05 // check it.
```

and getting 6E 00 **Class not supported**

Your other command is C0 - GET RESPONSE,

```
COMMAND = [
    0x00, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0B
]
```

This command is used to get the response from the card of length specified by previous command having return code like - 61 XX and APDU sequence should like 
**CLASS, INS, P1, P2, Le** //please check your Get Response command

Here Get Response giving 6700 , it seems correct because previous command is failed already and card does not have nothing to return to it so unable to return Le data ( 0x0B - Suppose it is your Le)

I suggest , understand your card well before firing any command, seems it is a **proprietary card** so you should know the file structure/CLASS byte USED before sending command, when you shoot with correct CLA value, hope you will not get - CLA not supported error.

Hope this information helps to identify the problem.

Comment: I checked command [here (page #7)](http://downloads.acs.com.hk/drivers/en/PMA_ACR38x%28CCID%29_v6.01.pdf) and tryed to get response, but i get `0x6e 0x00` again. I'm trying to get `SELECT_CARD_TYPE` for further interaction with the card, but it does not work. The result should be the `0x6e 0x00`. I send this for the test: `opensc-tool -s ff:a4:00:00:01:01 Using reader with a card: ACS ACR38U-CCID 00 00 Sending: FF A4 00 00 01 01 Received (SW1=0x6E, SW2=0x00)`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @IlyaSoltanov I can see "select card type" is very first command need to send and hope you are sending correct Lc byte ( 0x01 to 0x09 ) as per card used. this doc is not defining 6E00 status word. I think you should check with card datasheet/manual to understand card behaviour - when it could return 6E00 ( Class not supported)

Comment: unfortunately there is no documentation on the smart card.

Comment: @IlyaSoltanov: Without documentation you will have a VERY hard time (smart cards are very restrictive on purpose), in my opinion, you will not be able to complete any non-trivial task.